# Calling a function within the said function

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

How can i call a def from the same def? I mean, i want to do that:

```
def cal(cal):
    stat = stat_dict()
    profile = profile_dict()
    skill = skill_dict()
    ... Abreviation....
    elif cal == 'Phy': return round(stat['Str']*4 + stat['Con']/3 + stat['End']/2 + stat['Tou']/4 + stat['Agi']/6)
    elif cal == 'Inv': return round(cal('Phy') * (1 + skill['Hauling']/20))
```

I know that i can chage the last line to:

```
   elif cal == 'Inv': return round((stat['Str']*4 + stat['Con']/3 + stat['End']/2 + stat['Tou']/4 + stat['Agi']/6)* (1 + skill['Hauling']/20))
```

Or even:

```
def cal(cal):
  stat = stat_dict()
  profile = profile_dict()
  skill = skill_dict()
  X = round(stat['Str']*4 + stat['Con']/3 + stat['End']/2 + stat['Tou']/4 + stat['Agi']/6)
  .... Abreviation...
  elif cal == 'Phy': return X
  elif cal == 'Inv': retunr X * (1 + skill['Hauling']/20
```

But i don't want to do that, i want to cal the same def for a personal reason ... Is it possible? Sorry for my english. (Ah, also, i use python 3.6)

Comment: They're called "functions", not "defs".

Comment: you can do it, just do not call a variable and a function the same name, see http://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php

Comment: These are functions, and calling the function within this function is called recursion.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart oh sorry, english isn't my first languaje so i thought that functions and defs was the same to say.

Comment: @PawelKordowsky thanks, I had't realized that both was called cal and that was an error.

Comment: @Apero thank for the info, i didn't know that calling the fuction withing the same function was called 'recursion'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with the name of your parameter:

```
def cal(cal):
```

You've named the parameter the same thing as the function you're trying to call, so it *shadows* the function. If you say `cal` inside the function, you're referring to the parameter, not the function, as you intend.

Simply name your parameter (or function) something else. (`cal` is not a good, descriptive name for a function or a parameter anyway.)

Comment: Jonathon, I was just about to say this :) +1

Comment: Oh thank you a lot! i renamed de cal(cal) to cal(fcal) and it works perfectly! I didn't understand your last sentence, Why cal is bad? cal(cal) is my abreviaton of calculator(calculation) xD

Comment: *"Why cal is bad?"* The fact that you had to ask this question on Stack Overflow is a perfect example of why it's bad: because it's too short and ambiguous, and makes it easy to accidentally create a name collision.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart a ok, so it's better if i call the function calculator, thanks.